# Prove operation on binary relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

There is a relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ when $a+b=c+d$. Let $R={[(a,b)]:(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}$ (i.e $R$ is the set of all equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$). 
Is $[(x,y)]*[(w,z)]=[(x+w,y+z)]$ well defined? ----After several examples, I think it is well defined. $[(2,3)]*[(4,5)]=[(6,8)]$,  $[(1,4)]*[(2,7)]=[(3,11)]$ and $(6,8)\sim(3,11)$...
But I am not sure how to prove it in a general way. Please help!

Comment: You don't need to write $(a,b)$~$(c,d)$.  You can write $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$, entirely within MathJax.  It has proper spacing that way, and the fonts match.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ (a,b)\sim(c,d)$ and $(e,f)\sim(g,h)$. Thus $a+b=c+d, e+f=g+h$. This implies $a+b+e+f=c+d+g+h$. Thus $(a+e)+(b+f)=(c+g)+(d+h)$. Hence $(a+e,b+f)\sim (c+d,g+h)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that for any $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ such that $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ and $(e,f)\sim(g,h)$ then $(a,b)*(e,f)\sim(c,d)*(g,h)$.

Comment: So you mean for example, If $(2,3)$~$(4,5)$, $(1,4)$~$(2,7)$, then, $(3,7)$~$(6,12)$??

Comment: That is what I mean if you do it algebraically.  Prove that if $(a,b)\,\text{~}\,(c,d)$ and $(e,f)\,\text{~}\,(g,h)$, then, $(a+e,b+f)\,\text{~}\,(c+g,d+h)$.

Comment: But $(3,7)$\not~$(6,12)$ ?? It is $3+6\not=7+12$ I am confused.

Comment: Is it not well defined ?

Comment: In your example neither $(2,3)\,\text{~}\,(4,5)$.  So if the premise is false don't expect the conclusion to be true.

Comment: Wait,,,, Why $(2,3)$~$(4,5)$???They are not necessarily relation, are they? I made those examples with my prof.  Oh, I am so confused.

Comment: The code said \,\text{~}\,.  It looks as if attention to proper spacing was done deliberately.  I changed it to \sim.  Thus: $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ is coded as (a,b)\sim(c,d).  Proper spacing and matching of fonts is left to the software.  TeX was invented for tihngs like this.